# Firebase initialization Exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[Created firebase console account for my flutter project and also add firebase android file to my android app gradle.
Add firebase package in pub.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJV9j.png)

its give an exception how to resolve the error ?
[App level Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT5xt.png)
[Project level Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXOyF.png)

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show both the code and the error as *text* rather than screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately, many people who might have been willing to help will not be able to read pictures of code on their devices. Also, in the future, people with a similar problem are less likely to find your question and any answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your `main()` function should be:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

not

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
```